# Sumar la cantidad de valores sin repetir los ítems de un Array

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Tengo una tabla en mi bd llamada **Pagos**, y dentro de la tabla, tengo una columna llamada **servicios**, donde almaceno los id's de los servicios registrados en un pago, separados por ',' (comas):

**Tabla Pagos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Servicios:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito saber cuáles son los servicios más vendidos según los registros de mi 
tabla de pagos. 
Empleo el patrón **MVC** en mi código, y para la necesidad de obtener los servicios más vendidos traté de hacer lo siguiente:

En una clase en el Modelo, tengo la consulta SQL de la tabla de pagos, y en otra clase de otro Modelo, tengo otra consulta SQL de la tabla de los servicios; entonces, en el archivo donde necesito imprimir los datos, hice lo sigueinte:

```
<?php

$pagos = ControladorPagos::ctrMostrarPagos(); //Ésto me trae todos los datos de la tabla "pagos"

$cantidadServicios = array();

foreach ($pagos as $key => $value) {

    $nomServicios = explode(',', $value["servicios"]); //Convierto los servicios en array que están separados por comas (',')

    for ($i=0; $i < count($nomServicios); $i++){

        $servicios = ControladorServicios::ctrMostrarServicios("id", $nomServicios[$i]); //Traigo los servicios según el id que estén registrados en pagos

        $cantidadServicios = array($servicios["nombre"] => count($nomServicios));

        var_dump($cantidadServicios);

    }

}

?>
```

Ésto es lo que me imprime el var_dump():

```
array(1) { ["Mensualidad 7H 3 días"]=> int(2) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 4H * 4 Días"]=> int(2) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 2H 3 días"]=> int(2) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 7H 3 días"]=> int(2) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 4H * 4 Días"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 7H 3 días"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["Mensualidad 5H 3 días"]=> int(1) }
```

Pero necesito que se me muestre el total de veces por servicio, no que se me repitan los servicios. Ejm:

Mensualidad 7H 3 días => 3       // (3 veces comprado)

Mensualidad 4H * 4 Días => 2     // (2 veces comprado)

Mensualidad 2H * 4 Días => 1     // (1 vez comprado)
etc...

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Una forma de hacerlo sería contando directamente en la consulta SQL mediante `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM pagos GROUP BY servicios` pero para ello tendrías que haber guardado una fila por cada `id`, no valores separados por `,` lo cual dificulta situaciones como estas, aparte de posibles errores que se pueden cometer al insertar los datos con errores (espacios en blanco, ids incorrectos, caracteres mezclados con números, etc).

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en un pago, pueden haber varios servicios, por lo que decidí guardar los servicios que se registren en un pago separados por comas...

Comment: Entiendo, pero cuando diseñas el modelo de datos tienes que tener en cuenta los requerimientos sobre ese modelo. Este requerimiento en concreto demuestra que debiste crear una tabla `pago_servicio` donde guardes una fila por cada pago y por cada tipo de servicio. Usar una lista separada por comas para esto no sólo va a complicar consultas como las que se plantean aquí, sino también futuras consultas de tipo estadístico como por ejemplo: *cuántas veces  se requirió el servicio `X` entre las fechas tal y tal*, etc. Aparte de lo que te puede costar controlar los errores en esa columna.

Comment: Quizá pueda sonar un poco complejo de desarrollar, pero encontré un post con la misma necesidad, sólo que yo no la supe ejecutar bien...
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/sumar-valores-elementos-repetidos-array-919631/

Comment: El problema es que tú estás centrado en resolver desde PHP un problema que ha venido a ser complejo debido al modelo de datos que has implementado. Como ya dije, mantener ese modelo de datos va a ser a la larga muy costoso, no sólo por lo difícil que resulta obtener un resultado banal como un simple conteo, sino porque todo eso casi seguro que a la larga terminará siendo un spaghetti. La diferencia es que quizá cuando eso ocurra vas a tener una BD en producción mal diseñada, con varios miles o millones de registros que empezarán a arrojar resultados erróneos, o a ralentizar el sistema, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos casos MySQL tiene una función muy útil: `find_in_set()` para encontrar un valor en una cadena de valores separados por comas.

Lo que necesitas sale en una consulta:

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.nombre
     , count(1)
  FROM servicios s
    JOIN pagos p
      ON find_in_set(s.id,p.servicios)
  GROUP BY s.id
         , s.nombre
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, mil gracias.

Comment: amigo, ¿puedes ayudarme con ésta preguntica por favor https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/328935/109858 ?