# Buscar un caracter en una columna SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla en mi bd llamada **pagos**, y en ella tengo una columna llamada **deportistas** con los id's de varios deportistas en una sola fila:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son los deportistas a los que se les registró ese pago.

Ahora lo que necesito es hacer una consulta entre la tabla **pagos** y la tabla **deportistas** para ver la información del deportista que esté registrado en un pago, pero no sé cómo comparar el id de la tabla deportista con el que esté dentro de la columna deportistas de la tabla pagos...

Ésta es mi tabla **deportistas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ésto es lo que he intentado hasta el momento, pero no lo he conseguido:

```
SELECT p.id, d.id FROM pagos p 
INNER JOIN deportistas d ON p.deportistas = d.id 
WHERE d.id = 2
```

Sólo me retorna una fila con el primer pago, pero yo necesito que me retorne todos los pagos donde está ese id (2) en la columna deportistas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues la consulta parece correcta yo solo veo el ID 2 una vez

Comment: Necesitas normalizar tus tablas o nunca tendrás un rendimiento aceptable ni código sencillo.

Comment: @Aprendiz, el Deportista `2` está en el pago id `1` y en el pago id `2`

Comment: Manejar una lista de deportistas separados por coma rompe cualquier posibilidad de hacer un join como el que estás intentado. ¿Tienes posibilidad de modificar la estructura de tus datos?

Comment: a mi parecer, te falta una tabla  Pagos_deportistas (M:M) para que sea optima tu consulta de pagos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues hacerlo usando la función [`find_in_set`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp), por ejemplo, para obtener todos los deportistas de un determinado pago:

```
select * from deportista d where 
   exists (select 1 from pagos p where 
             p.id = 2 and
             find_in_set(d.id, p.deportistas) > 0)
```

La query mostrará todos los deportistas asociados al pago con `ID = 2`

Por otro lado, desde mi punto de vista, el modelo de datos es algo extraño, no está normalizado, la relación entre pagos y deportistas debería tener una tabla de relación que una mediante FKs ambas tablas, dicho de otra forma, la relación (cardinalidad) entre deportista y pago es n:n (Varios a Varios) https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n

Answer (score 1):

No tenemos ejemplos del resultado esperado, pero a partir de ésta consulta puedes adecuar:

```
SELECT p.codigo_pago
     , d.edad
  FROM pagos p
    INNER JOIN deportistas d
      ON find_in_set(d.id, p.deportistas);
```

Precisamente la función `find_in_set()` permite hacer el JOIN.

Comment: ¿Y permite usar índices? ¿O estará destinado a ser lento por siempre?

Comment: @Luis Cazares: Ni uno ni otro. No usará índices, es el precio de no normalizar; sin embargo, cuando la columna es de tipo `SET` ocurren optimizaciones.